# How should I specify ERROR return arguments in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_tests]
    @ErrorLine INT OUTPUT,
    @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT,
    @ErrorProcedure NVARCHAR(100) OUTPUT,
    @ErrorNumber INT OUTPUT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    //
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE()
        SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        SET @ErrorProcedure = ERROR_PROCEDURE()
        SET @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER()
        RETURN
    END CATCH
```

Can someone advise me is this a good way to declare the error information? Any additional advice or suggestions would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of handling the errors is good to proceed with. You can also have a look at [MSDN: Using TRY...CATCH in Transact-SQL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296(v=sql.105).aspx):

> - If the stored procedure does not contain its own TRY…CATCH construct,    the error returns control to the CATCH block associated
>     with the TRY    block that contains the EXECUTE statement.
> - If the stored procedure contains a TRY…CATCH construct, the error       transfers control to the CATCH block in the stored procedure. When the CATCH block code finishes, control is passed back to the statement immediately after the EXECUTE statement that called the
>     stored procedure.

The other way is to use the `select` statement in your `CATCH` block to select the errors like:

```
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
        ERROR_STATE() as ErrorState,
        ERROR_PROCEDURE() as ErrorProcedure,
        ERROR_LINE() as ErrorLine,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage;
END CATCH
```